# Missing users after clean install and separate home partition

Tags: system-installation, home-directory

I had three users, One Admin and two standard, in a separate /home partition running 10.04.

I did a clean install of 11.10 by checking the format / and /swap boxes in the partition section of the install program.  The program then asked for an Admin name and I gave it the same user name and password as the Admin on 10.04.

When I completed the install The Admin account was the only available user at start up.   When logging in as user I have all my previous user setting as I had in 10.04.  Yet there are no standard user!

I went to the terminal and listed the home directories and the standard users /home directory data is still there.   How come 11.10 does not recognize them?

Answer (score 2):

So your /home directory contains home folders for `adminuser`, `usera` and `userb`. These folders were created by the old system.

During installation, you created a new user, `adminuser`, with same name as the `adminuser` in the old system. The new system you just installed is correctly using `/home/adminuser` as `adminuser`'s home folder.

You can't log in as `usera` or `userb` yet because you have to create those other users in the new system, too.

In Settings, click on User Accounts and create new users with the same names as those home folders.

Comment: The aforementioned approach does not work.  I think it has something to do with the numerical number assigned to a User.  I believe the system ID number assigned to the first user created, in this case the adminuser, where the same by default during both installs.  I do know know hte user ID numbers assigned to the other users and I believe that creating a new usera creates a new user with the same name and a different user ID number than usera that existed from the old install.

Comment: Your old users from the old install don't exist anymore. Their home directories do, but users and home directories are not the same thing. Please open a terminal and run `ls -l /home` then show us the output.